# Subset and filter not giving proper answer

Tags: r

I have following dataset and used `subset` and `filter` to segment the data:

```
KL <- read.table(text = "
ID  C1
A   597.69
B   239.64
C   601.3
D   4052.6
E   73.73
F   74.06
G   124
H   0
I   0
J   0
K   0
L   122.45
M   152.88
N   123.32
O   354.12",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
header = TRUE)

str(KL)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ C1: num  597.7 239.6 601.3 4052.6 73.7 ...
```

When I applied subset conditions

```
cl4  = subset(KL, C1 > "300.00")
```

Output is:

```
ID C1
A  597.69
C  601.30
D  4052.60
E  73.73
F  74.06
O  354.12
```

Why is it still showing number less than 300?

I have tried `filter` also but the output is same.

Comment: Aren't column `C1` numeric ? Shouldn't it be `subset(KL, C1 > 300.00)`  without quotes?

Comment: If `C1` isn't numeric, then what you are trying to do is just plain wrong.  If you need that column to be treated numerically, then make it numeric.

Comment: To push the point home, you are doing a *textual* comparison, not a numerical one. Realize that `"2" > "11"` because the "2" is a higher letter than the "1" (regardless of the following characters). This explains why the first five of your output are there: "4" through "7" are all later (higher) in the letter-order than "3", and in the last one, "5" (of 354.12) is higher than "0" (of 300.00). This error suggests the need to review basic tenets of R data types.

Comment: Note to "Close" voters. This is *not* a typographical error. That's something like typing "polt(x)" instead of "plot(x)". This is a misunderstanding of how R deals with types, and if there isn't a suitable duplicate question then this should not be closed.

Comment: I agree with @Spacedman, which is why I edited the question. It's a fine question, and not unusual misunderstanding for a user new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your column `C1` is numeric, you should not use quotes. Try this:

```
 subset(KL, C1 > 300)

   ID      C1
1   A  597.69
3   C  601.30
4   D 4052.60
15  O  354.12
```

But note that you should use caution with `subset()` - this will not always do what you think it does.

It's better to use `[` for subsetting:

```
KL[KL$C1 > 300, ]
   ID      C1
1   A  597.69
3   C  601.30
4   D 4052.60
15  O  354.12
```